# Compile Corona?

Tags: linux, centos, centos5

Trying to compile corona on CentOs5.

When I run ./configure I get

```
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... /lib/cpp
configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details.
```

Tried downloading an rpm and it said missing dependencies

libgif.so.4 is needed by corona-1.0.2-2.i486
rpmlib(PayloadIsLzma)

Although after looking at that, I am guessing I downloaded an rpm not for centos5?

(Ugh, I can never get pre/code to work :|. Even though it looks fine in the preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need g++ compiler. To install:
yum install g++

Comment: "No package g++ available." What repo can I find it in?

Comment: Ah, it is "gcc-c++".

Comment: "SaveTGA.cpp:2:17: error: png.h: No such file or directory"

Comment: install libpng and libpng-devel